# Mulitple Read More buttons not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a site built on wordpress, salient theme, using visual composer.

The site is http://kingkongco.com.au/c-cor/about-us/
(sorry if it runs slow, on a server with hundreds of others!)

If you scroll down, you'll see the staff section,9 people each with a read more function.

The problems are:

- when the user opens two or more blocks, and then hits one block's 'hide content', it turns back on the 'read more' for all open blocks
- Also, when opened, the text styles left-align (YAY!) but when closed, it does not revert back to center-align.

I recommend to inspect the html using firebug (or something similar) as this was built in salient's visual composer, however, here is all relevent code to this situation:

HTML and (each block is identical except for content) the footer funtion:

```js
(function($) {
  $('.showcontent').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().next('p').show();
    $(this).parent("p").css("text-align", "left");
  })
  $('.hidecontent').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $('.showcontent').show();
    $(this).parent("p").css("text-align", "center");
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img title="Howard Rupert" src="http://kingkongco.com.au/c-cor/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/profile1.png" alt="Howard Rupert" />
<h4 class="light">Howard Rupert</h4>
<div class="position">account director</div>
<p class="description">Howard is a highly capable, deeply experienced technical sales leader with a wealth of exposure to HFC Connectivity Equipment since 1989. Today he leads C-COR’s CONNECTIONS product
  <a class="showcontent">Read more…</a>
</p>
<p class="cdscontainer">line which includes passive products such as coaxial cable, coaxial hard-line, cable connectors, optical cable, optical connectors, Taps and all other passive devices plus DOCSIS and RF test equipment. Howard joined C-COR from Pacific Broadband Networks
  in 2014 where he was Sales Director for North America and Oceania sales. Previously, he served an extensive career with C-COR Inc. originally in USA and then in Hong Kong as an AsiaPac account leader. He developed country plans and engaged manufacturing
  product line management for Connectivity Equipment requirements. Howard started in the DOCSIS Cable Networks industry in 1989. In this time, Howard has been part of an industry evolution from CableLabs DOCSIS 1.0 to the emerging DOCSIS 3.1 standard.
  With over 25 years of international technical sales experience Howard has been engaged in optical cables, coaxial cables including experience in military product specifications and high current connectors. Howard was awarded a Masters of Business Administration
  (University of Western Ontario) and a Bachelor of Science (Pennsylvania State University).
  <a class="hidecontent">...Hide Content</a>
</p>
```

Thanks for any help/advice/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try this replace `this` with `showcontent` class.

When you click on read more I am basically hiding all the showcontent classes and then I am just opening the single one that you clicked.

```
(function($) {
$('.showcontent').click(function(){
  $('.showcontent').hide();
  $(this).parent().next('p').show();
  $(this).parent("p").css("text-align", "left");
})
$('.hidecontent').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
  $('.showcontent').show();
  $(this).parent("p").css("text-align", "center");
})
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Please explain your approach.

Comment: When you click on read more I am basically hiding all the showcontent classes and then I am just opening the single one that you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

whats happening in your code is that the ".showcontent" selector is selecting all the classes from a document, but in my code i am first selecting the parent div and then finding the ".showcontent" class to make the changes. it goes same with the 'p' tag as my code is aligning all 'p' tage in a div to center or as you need it:

```
(function($) {
$('.showcontent').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).next('p').show();
  $(this).closest("div").find("p").css("text-align", "left"); //changed
});
$('.hidecontent').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
  $(this).closest("div").find('.showcontent').show(); //changed
  $(this).closest("div").find("p").css("text-align", "center"); //changed
});
})( jQuery
```

Comment: Please explain your approach.

Comment: whats happening in your code is that the ".showcontent" selector is selecting all the classes from a document, but in my code i am first selecting the parent div and then finding the ".showcontent" class to make the changes. it goes same with the 'p' tag as my code is aligning all 'p' tage in a div to center or as you need it